# Литература по языку программирования Haskell

Tags: книги, haskell

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите литературу по языку программирования Haskell. Желательно на русском. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть бесплатный интернет журнал [Практика функционального программирования](http://fprog.ru/)

Там статьи про функциональные языки, большая часть по хаскелю, есть статьи с основами хаскеля, есть для продвинутых. В конце статей часто приведен список литературы. В каком то номере проведен обзор литературы по каждому языку программирования. Я себе заказал в распечатанном виде, наслаждаюсь.

Answer (score 6):

**Каждую из ниже перечисленных книг рекомендую особо:**

**1.** [О Haskell по-человечески](http://ohaskell.dshevchenko.biz)

**2.** [Учебник по Haskell](http://anton-k.github.io/ru-haskell-book/book/home.html)

**Наиболее известные:**

- [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good! (ENG)](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

Есть бумажный вариант на русском. Она же [онлайн](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4637689)

[Полезные ссылки](http://ru.learnhaskellforgood.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8_Haskell_%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0!_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8)

- [Real World Haskell](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3824100)
- [Haskell: The Craft of Functional Programming (2nd Edition)](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1339294)
- [The Haskell Road To Logic, Math And Programming](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1339264)

**Разное:**

- Душкин - [14 занимательных эссе о языке Haskell и функциональном программировании](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3599283)
- Душкин - [Справочник по языку Haskell](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3650160)
- [Функциональное программирование на примере языка Haskell](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4056296)
- [Beginning Haskell (ENG)](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4986717)

**Web-программирование**

- [Developing Web Apps with Haskell and Yesod: Safety-Driven Web Development, 2nd Edition](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4976901)

[Онлайн вариант с множеством примеров](http://www.yesodweb.com/)

[Русский вариант](http://eax.me/yesod-introduction/)